# How to fix Django Translation ASCII decode error?

Tags: python, django, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I have this django website translating from english to german from the locale/lc_messages/django.po and django.mo files. But, when i try to translate the words which are in german letters like ü and ä, it gives me the error

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

As far as I can think, django is trying to decode the unicode characters through ASCII which is not possible. But how do i fix this ? Where should I make the setting for django to decode through utf-8 and not through ASCII. Or let me know if I am wrong.

traceback:

```
DjangoUnicodeDecodeError at /de/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x0000000005EB40B8> (<class 'django.utils.functional.__proxy__'>)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/de/
Django Version: 1.10.1
Exception Type: DjangoUnicodeDecodeError
Exception Value:    
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x0000000005EB40B8> (<class 'django.utils.functional.__proxy__'>)
Exception Location: C:\Users\deybala1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py in force_text, line 88
Python Executable:  C:\Users\deybala1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.11
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\deybala1\\Documents\\pe-locator',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\pyexcel-0.2.3-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\django_registration-2.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\django_http_proxy-0.4.3-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\django_redis-4.4.4-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\django_redis_sessions-0.5.6-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2',
 'c:\\users\\deybala1\\appdata\\local\\continuum\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\sphinx-1.3.5-py2.7.egg',
 'c:\\users\\deybala1\\appdata\\local\\continuum\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-20.3-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\deybala1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Fr, 28 Okt 2016 04:58:23 -0500
Unicode error hint

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: ne pr��fung
```

This is my msgid and msgstr from django.po

```
#: .\app\templates\app\layout.html:47
msgid "Take Exam"
msgstr "Eine prüfung anlegen"
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Do you have `# coding: utf-8` on first line of your file?

Comment: where do you want me to have that ? I tried putting it over all the py files in my project. But is it due to that ? I think the error is while decoding the utf 8 to ascii.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution, had to put the header in all .po files at top.

```
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
```

Thanks for helping guys. It is better solution to use **poedit** for working with .po files

Answer (score 0):

Could there be a problem in the po file (it is python 2.7)? You can try:

```
msgstr u"Eine prüfung anlegen"
```

Comment: I tried msgstr "u'Eine prüfung anlegen'". But doesn't work. same error. And yes it is python 2.7